# Filezilla Cannot add key file SFTP

Tags: putty, filezilla

I'm new to this and want to connect to my .ppk file using filezilla. But the problem is whenever I tried adding key file it doesnt really add in filezilla

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvsI.png)

When adding file I was able to click the .ppk file but when I press open it doesnt add in the filezilla private key list like showed in the picture

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem trying to use the .ppk files generated by cPanal.  I ran the conversion tool built into cPanel and downloaded the .ppk file but when I try to select it in FileZilla it never works.  Most of the time it either sets to the first .ppk file in the folder I'm in or it stays blank but in all cases, it doesn't work.

A 4-month-old posting on this site, https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/12461, says that it appears to be due to an upgrade in the PuTTY PPK file format to v3 which is only supported in FileZilla v3.55+.  I happen to run a Linux desktop and the distro version of my copy of FileZilla is v3.52.  So looks like I need to wait till the distro catches it up.

Try just installing the latest version and trying again.

Comment: Upgrading to latest version of FileZilla worked for me.